# Meteor app using subdomain for user accounts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, subdomain

I'm writing an app using Meteor for company inventory management. Each company will get their own subdomain, but essentially they'll all be using the same code & routes, the only difference being that depending on the subdomain the subscribe/publish/log-in will be unique to that subdomain.

For example, costco.myapp.com will only subscribe to the data that pertains only to costco.

My question would be how do I successfully create/implement subdomains using Meteor that use the exact same code/routes, but publish collection info only relevant to that subdomain?

Comment: I think you forgot to ask your question and what you tried to do.

Comment: Did you solve problem?

Comment: I am wondering if you solved this too :}

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to know how to inspect the app url using Meteor.

Normally this would be accomplished with `Meteor.absoluteUrl()`
However, this uses the `ROOT_URL` environment variable, so you will not be able use it to differentiate different urls for the same app instance.

On the client use plain old `window.location.hostname` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Do I need to create each subdomain in node? Or is there anyway I have all *.myapp.com as sort of a mask use the same code and just parse the url for subscription purposes?